# Loading timePickerDialog from a fragment

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker, layout-inflater, findviewbyid

I am trying to use a custom time picker and then run the picker from a fragment. This is the code for the time picker dialog (TimePickerFragment.java):

```
package com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    public TimePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_picker, container, false);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

and this is the code from the onCreateView fragment that shows the time picker (WorkdayFragment.java):

```
mButtonEnd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.end_workday);
mButtonEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TimePickerFragment dialog = new TimePickerFragment();
        dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TIME);
    }
});
```

This is the error I'm getting when pressing the button. It seems like there is a problem loading the view:

```
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock, PID: 20325
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:317)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:231)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:499)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2244)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1002)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:482)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-25 16:24:46.696 20325-20325/com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My guess is that there is a problem with the way the time picker code is written because when I replace it with date picker then everything runs without errors.

I tried to solve the requestFeature() error according to other answers on this topic with no progress.

Any advice on how to continue from here would be very helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: I see that why should you override onCreateView method of DialogFragment. You already return the timer picker dialog.

Comment: You are right, problem solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey first of all you need to remove the onCreateView of your timepicker fragment.
I also could find in example share with me.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
```

So your TimerPickerFragment should look like below

```
package com.ravit.android.aroundtheclock;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    public TimePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

> Caution: If your app supports versions of Android lower than 3.0, be
>   sure that you call getSupportFragmentManager() to acquire an instance
>   of FragmentManager. Also make sure that your activity that displays
>   the time picker extends FragmentActivity instead of the standard
>   Activity class.

```
mButtonEnd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.end_workday);
mButtonEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DialogFragment newFragment  = new TimePickerFragment();
        //newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TIME);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TIME);
        // if you are using the nested fragment then user the 
        //newFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), DIALOG_TIME);
    }
});
```

Let me know if you have any question. thanks

Comment: I do have a question, why did you use the getSupportFragmentManager instead of getActivity().getFragmentManager()?

Comment: If your app supports versions of Android lower than 3.0, be sure that you call getSupportFragmentManager() to acquire an instance of FragmentManager. other wise it is find if you use default Fragment Manager,

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: useful answer.. saved me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example, which can be used either from Fragment and Activity:

```
public class TimePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_HOUR = "ARGUMENT_HOUR";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_MINUTE = "ARGUMENT_MINUTE";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_IS_24_HOURS = "ARGUMENT_IS_24_HOURS";
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener;

    private int hourOfDay;
    private int minute;
    private boolean is24Hours;

    public static TimePickerDialogFragment newInstance(final int hour, final int minute, final boolean is24Hours) {
        final TimePickerDialogFragment df = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_HOUR, hour);
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_MINUTE, minute);
        args.putBoolean(ARGUMENT_IS_24_HOURS, is24Hours);
        df.setArguments(args);
        return df;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        retrieveArguments();
    }

    private void retrieveArguments() {
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            hourOfDay = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_HOUR);
            minute = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_MINUTE);
            is24Hours = args.getBoolean(ARGUMENT_IS_24_HOURS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), this.listener, this.hourOfDay, this.minute, this.is24Hours);
    }

    public void setListener(final TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Initialize and show it:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
final boolean is24Hours = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext());
final TimePickerDialogFragment timePicker = TimePickerDialogFragment.newInstance(
        c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
        c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
        is24Hours);
timePicker.setListener(this);
timePicker.showNow(getChildFragmentManager(), null);
```