# TimePickerDialog in a Fragment Class

Tags: android, classcastexception, timepicker

Can I implement

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
```

in a **Fragment class?**

if it is possible **HOW?**

this is my TimePickerFragment.class

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {


@NonNull
@Override

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int cHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int cMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), cHour, cMinute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
}
```

do I need to modify this code so i can use it in a Fragment class?

this is where i want to implement it

```
public class BluetoothFragment extends Fragment
```

i have already tried it
but i'm getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.bluetoothplantdroid.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener
```

Comment: First make a constructor in this class , i think you want to set the text , so make a constructor of the above class and pass context and textview as a parameter , now make the object of this class in the fragment and pass your context and textview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading timePickerDialog from a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330988/loading-timepickerdialog-from-a-fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below Code :
Pass Activity or Fragment context .

```
public static void setTimeFromTimePicker(Context context, EditText editText) {

        int hourOfDay, minute;

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hourOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog dpd = new TimePickerDialog(context, (timePicker, hourOfDay1, minute1) -> {

            Time time = new Time(hourOfDay1, minute1, 0);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
            SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.getDefault());
            String s = simpleDateFormat.format(time);
            editText.setText(s);
        }, hourOfDay, minute, false);

        dpd.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can *set Listener to your DialogFragment to get a callback* in origin fragment

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance() {
        return new TimePickerFragment();
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int cHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int cMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, cHour, cMinute,
                android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void setListener(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

This is how you can get a callback in origin fragment -

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

   May be click event of some widget... {
       TimePickerFragment.newInstance().setListener(this);
       // Show your dialog
   }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // data when time has been set.
    }

}
```

Comment: the `this` in the `setListener(this);` is a context or a event listener?

Comment: Its a `listener`. So that your Fragment will implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` and you get get data on `onTimeSet` when time gets selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    public TimePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
    }
}
```

**Caution: If your app supports versions of Android lower than 3.0, be sure that you call getSupportFragmentManager() to acquire an instance of FragmentManager. Also make sure that your activity that displays the time picker extends FragmentActivity instead of the standard Activity class.**