# How to create a TimePickerDIalog from BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, timepicker

Im working with DatepickerDialog & TimePickerDialog, i've built a Datepicker but i cant make works the DatePickerDialog . can i implement this as i did with the DatepickerDialog ?

This is my code:

```
private void timePicker(){

int hour = 0;
int minute = 0;
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;
timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePickerDialog view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(hourOfDay), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}, hour, minute, false);

public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) +"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear)
                    +"-"+String.valueOf(year);
            textViewDate.setText(date);
        }
    }, yy, mm, dd);
    datePicker.show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: After searching for days, I finally found a good answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613108/5319007

Answer (score 0):

just for testing purposes, try using the newer fragment class, not the compatibility one.  They are not compatible with each other.